# How to convert each char in string to 8 bit int? JAVA

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, bit

I've been suggested a TCP-like checksum, which consists of the sum of the (integer) sequence and ack field values, added to a character-by-character sum of the payload field of the packet (i.e., treat each character as if it were an 8 bit integer and just add them together).

I'm assuming it would go along the lines of:

```
char[] a = data.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; int < len; i++) {
   ...
}
```

Though I'm pretty clueless as to how I could complete the actual conversion?

My `data` is `string`, and I wish to go through the string (converted to a char array (though if there's a better way to do this let me know!)) and now I'm ready to iterate though how does one convert each character to an int. I will then be summing the total.

Comment: simple: in your for loop: `int val = a[i];`

Comment: and this converts the current character in the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As String contains Unicode, and `char` is a two-byte UTF-16 implementation of Unicode, it might be better to first convert the String to bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
data = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // Inverse.

int crc = 0;
for (byte b : bytes) {
    int n = b & 0xFF; // An int 0 .. 255 without sign extension
    crc ^= n;
}
```

Now you can handle any Unicode content of a String. UTF-8 is optimal when sufficient ASCII letters are used, like Chinese HTML pages. (For a Chinese plain text UTF-16 might be better.)

Comment: How would I now go from `[B@106d69c` to an integer?

Comment: `byte` is a _signed_ 8 bit integer, hence you are almost there. I added an example for loop. The toString of a byte array is just its type code `[B` (array of byte) and object address/handle `@106d69c`

Comment: The above loop provides me with an outcome of 0, I don't understand why you would use the XOR operand?

Comment: That was just an example, the calculation I leave as your effort (+=, and that ack field). So not to suggest having a result; info fails.